# __proto__ and prototype alternative in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype

I have to rewrite the Javascript into Typescript (also new to both languages) so I am really confused in the below syntax;

```
IosXHR.prototype.__proto__ = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
```

I don't know how to write this in typescript. 
Below is the whole snippet of code.

```
var IosXHR=function(){
 var thisXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
//code...
//code...
}
IosXHR.prototype.__proto__ = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
```

Comment: Is there a specific problem writing that? JavaScript is valid TypeScript, too. But maybe `class IosXHR extends XMLHttpRequest { ... }` (using ES6 classes, also supported by TS)?

Comment: Any Javascript is valid Typescript. Why do you think you need to fundamentally rewrite it?

Comment: Use [Object.setPrototypeOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf) or [extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends).

Comment: I am not facing any problem but I want to migrate my code slowly from JS to TS completely. I have Reveal Module Pattern in my JS code, I converted everything in Namespace but confused here.